# How to set date range for date of birth and date of death in vue.js datepicker?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

What i want to do is disable all the dates after today onward in both fields, And if date of death select first, in date of birth field disable all dates after date of death....
So far what i've done is like below

```
<Datepicker 
  :disabled-dates="disabledDates"
  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
  id="deceased_date_of_birth"
  input-class="form-control m-input"
  v-model="models.date_of_birth"
>
</Datepicker>
<Datepicker 
  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
  id="deceased_date_of_death"
  input-class="form-control m-input"
  v-model="models.date_of_death"
>
</Datepicker>

export default {
     data() {
      return {
            disabledDates: {
                to:this.setDateRange()
               },
             }

 methods: {
            setDateRange(){
                let x = new Date();
                console.log(x);
                return x;
            },
          }

        }
```

please give me a way to do this

Comment: what **Datepicker** package you using ?

Comment: i'm using vuejs-datepicker @Hamelraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this solution

Add this code in your component

> template

```
<Datepicker 
  :disabled-dates="disabledBirthDate"
  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
  id="deceased_date_of_birth"
  input-class="form-control m-input"
  v-model="models.date_of_birth"
>
</Datepicker>
<Datepicker 
  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
  :disabled-dates="disabledDeathDate"
  id="deceased_date_of_death"
  input-class="form-control m-input"
  v-model="models.date_of_death"
>
</Datepicker>
```

> data

```
data:()=>{
  return {
    models:{
       date_of_birth:null,
       date_of_death: null
    }
  }
}
```

> computed

```
disabledBirthDate: function () {
  return this.models.date_of_death ? {from: new Date(this.models.date_of_death)} : {from: new Date()};
},
disabledDeathDate: function () {
  return this.formData.from ? {from: new Date(), to: new Date(this.formData.from)} : {from: new Date()};
},
```

Comment: Thank you! your code is working properly. But i want to desable all the dates after today in both fields too... how can i do that?

Comment: This code will disable dates after today in both fields in the initial/default case. Do you need that every time?

Comment: initially dates after today fields have disabled, but after selecting a date it makes enable

Comment: `{from: new Date()}` will disable dates after today. You can add this inside the object returning in the `true` condition too. In the `disabledBirthDate`, need to add two `from` value in this case. I'm not sure if that possible. Will update you once I got the solution.

Comment: Hi, the solution mentioned in my previous comment will fix this. I've updated the answer. Please check it.

Comment: return this.models.deceased_date_of_birth ? {to: new Date(this.models.deceased_date_of_birth), from: new Date()} : {from: new Date()}; yeah yeah this worked.... thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need a computed property for each of the `:disabled-dates` binding for the date of birth and date of death datepickers:

```
<Datepicker 
  :disabled="isSyncEnabledInTenant != null ?  true : false"
  :disabled-dates="dateOfBirthDisabledDates"
  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
  id="deceased_date_of_birth"
  input-class="form-control m-input"
  v-model="models.date_of_birth"
>
</Datepicker>
<Datepicker 
  :disabled="isSyncEnabledInTenant != null ?  true : false"
  :disabled-dates="dateOfDeathDisabledDates"
  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
  id="deceased_date_of_death"
  input-class="form-control m-input"
  v-model="models.date_of_death"
>
```

Then, in your computed property, you can simply return the correct payload:

- You want to disable dates in the date of birth datepicker, that occur later than the date of death. This is specified using `from`.
- You want to disable dates in the date of death datepicker, that occur earlier than the date of birth. This is specified using `to`.
- You might want to add checks if the birth/death dates are provided first

The computed props will look like this:

```
computed: {
  // For date of birth, it cannot be later than date of death
  // So we use `from`
  dateOfBirthDisabledDates() {
    if (!this.models.date_of_death) return {};

    return {
      from: this.models.date_of_death;
    };
  },

  // For date of death, it cannot be earlier than date of death
  // So we use `to`
  dateOfDeathDisabledDates() {
    if (!this.models.date_of_birth) return {};

    return {
      to: this.models.date_of_birth
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering... But this gives me error like TypeError: "date.getFullYear is not a function"

Comment: Sounds like you're providing a non-date object? What is the value of `models.date_of_birth` and `models.date_of_death`?

Comment: Mon Mar 02 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) Fri Mar 27 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: Maybe try sharing a minimal, concrete and verifiable example.

Comment: i tried with your code and it worked, what hapend previously is i was trying change the dates which already been saved to db. Your code is actually working. is there any way to disable all the dates after today? Thank you very much

Comment: dateOfBirthDisabledDates() {
               
                if (!this.models.deceased_date_of_birth){
                    return {
                        from: this.models.deceased_date_of_death,
                    };
                }else {
                    return {
                        from: this.models.deceased_date_of_death
                    };
                }
                },  added from: this.models.deceased_date_of_death, line